# Event for marker position change

Tags: android, android-maps, android-maps-v2

I'm using the new Google Maps for Android v2.
Is there a way to set a listener for marker position change? For example when the user drag the marker.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Quoting [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker#marker_drag_events):

> You can use an OnMarkerDragListener to listen for drag events on a marker. To set this listener on the map, call GoogleMap.setOnMarkerDragListener. To drag a marker, a user must long press on the marker. When the user takes their finger off the screen, the marker will stay in that position. When a marker is dragged, onMarkerDragStart(Marker) is called initially. While the marker is being dragged, onMarkerDrag(Marker) is called constantly. At the end of the drag onMarkerDragEnd(Marker) is called. You can get the position of the marker at any time by calling Marker.getPosition().

[Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MapsV2/Drag) demonstrating the use of an `OnMarkerDragListener`.

Comment: Now wanted to add a twist to this question: need to implement "Undo Move" scenario for a given marker. The problem is that during onMarkerDragStart(..) marker.getPosition() reports LatLng that is different from original (in my experience marker "jumps" 1/2" above origin), so repositioning marker back to that position is useless. So, the fix seems to be the same as to infamous problem of keeping sync between markers and data model (unless there's a better solution?).

Comment: @esteewhy: "the fix seems to be the same as to infamous problem of keeping sync between markers and data model" -- probably. I see that same jump effect. If you have relatively few markers, maintain a `HashMap<Marker, Whatever>`, where `Whatever` is your data model. If you have lots of markers, maintain a `HashMap<Marker, Key>`, where `Key` is some means to go look up your data model in a database or something.

Comment: Exactly what i did, so it looks like a workaround. (Got a little relief after trying android-maps-extensions: don't have to use HashMap manually)