# How to temporarily suspend clustering in Android Map Extensions?

Tags: android-maps-extensions

I want to pause markers clustering during marker drag so that in process it won't be "trapped" by a nearest cluster.

It looks like a way to do it is to call **ClusteringSettings.enabled(false)**. The problem is that ClusteringSettings instance is not exposed from GoogleMap after it was passed in, i.e.: there's no method symmetric to **setClustering(ClusteringSettings)**.

What is a correct way to suspend clustering during marker drag?

**EDIT** [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16698553/exclude-marker-from-clustering-google-maps-extension-android-app) problem sounds related, but is not the same

Comment: Do you possibly call `setPosition` on any `Marker` during the process? The way it is implemented now it only notifies clustering engine when you stop dragging `Marker`.

Comment: @maciejgorski Yep, that seems to be it! I'm calling setPosition(..) in a course of repositioning marker (to mitigate the problem outlined here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14491069/event-for-marker-position-change/14491192#comment26063593_14491192).

Comment: .. So, now from a user perspective it looks like when you drop marker to a cluster, it "sinks" without a trace. Need to rethink my UI, perhaps.

Comment: Yes. That is a little quirk that should be easily resolved when [AME's Issue 10](http://code.google.com/p/android-maps-extensions/issues/detail?id=10) is implemented. You would just change clustering group, so it doesn't sink for a few seconds after it is released.